# Change option value within select input FROM URL Params

Tags: jquery, url, select, parameters

On this page: http://texomahondadealers.com/comparisons/

I am trying to create a script that will pull a parameter from URL that will change the value of the select that changes which vehicle is displayed against the Honda in the chart.

Gave this suggestion a try:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var prodId = getParameterByName('prodId');
$('#accord-car-comparison select').val(prodId);
```

However, it seemed to have no effect (using the link "http://texomahondadealers.com/comparisons/?name=fusion".

Any suggestions, solutions, or thoughts on why there are is no change to value would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$('#accord-car-comparison').val(prodId);` how about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the last 2 statements wrong. You are using **name** as parameter in url and the selector is wrong. It should be:

```js
var prodId = getParameterByName('name');
$('#accord-car-comparison').val(prodId);
```

Comment: Beautiful, I thought I was going to have to ask another question to get into a secondary level of making this page work the way I wanted, but you nailed this in a way that solved both of my issues.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just pulling it out of the request work?

```
var prodId = request.getParameter("name");
$('#accord-car-comparison select').val(prodId);
```

Comment: This is assuming you are staying with the parameter "name" from http://texomahondadealers.com/comparisons/?name=fusion